# ubuntu12.04 の box を立ち上げる際 hostnamectl: command not found

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

`vagrant up` をすると
`hostnamectl: command not found` と怒られてしまいます。
どこを修正していけばいいのでしょうか…。

情報が足りない部分ありましたら、ご指摘していただけますとありがたいです。

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu12.04'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: ietty_default_1436859130223_77096
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 3000 => 3000 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.2.10
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Setting hostname...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

hostnamectl set-hostname 'ubuntu-VirtualVox'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
bash: line 2: hostnamectl: command not found
```

`hostnamectl` に関する部分を調べていてもあまり理解できず解決せずです…。

`vagrant provision` をすると

```
$ vagrant provision
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible...

PLAY [vagrant] ****************************************************************

GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.33.10] => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 192.168.33.10 port 22: Operation timed out
    while connecting to 192.168.33.10:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.

TASK: [ubuntu | install essential packages] ***********************************
FATAL: no hosts matched or all hosts have already failed -- aborting


PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
           to retry, use: --limit @/Users/ietty/provision_vagrant.retry

192.168.33.10              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again
```

となってしまいます。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

これですね。

[Unable to set hostname in 12.04 · Issue #5934 · mitchellh/vagrant](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5934)

Ubuntu 13.04 から `hostnamectl` コマンドを使ってホスト名を設定するようになり、15.04 で旧来の `hostname` サービスによる設定が使えなくなりました。 [Vagrant でも 1.7.3 から新しい設定方法に対応した](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5673)ものの、 Ubuntu のバージョンを見て設定方法を切り替えるコードにバグがあったようです。

前述の Issue は既に修正が行われており、 Vagrant 1.7.4 でリリースされる予定です。

- 1.7.4 を待つ
- 1.7.3 にダウングレードする
- とりあえずパッチを手動で適用してしまう（[`return` を書き足すだけ](https://github.com/aidanhs/vagrant/commit/13e2dbaf9d1a63ebbb7d11b4e844cab2f36d5bfc)）

あたりが対処法になるかと思います。